# Machine replacement with Markov chain model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Assume we inspect a system periodically for a certain time period. After each inspection, we classify the system states into exactly one of the states in $\left\{0, 1, \ldots, M\right\}$. State $0$ indicates the best condition of the machine, while state $L$ means the machine is inoperative. During every periods, the system state is likely to degrade by $1$ unit with probability $p$.

(a) Let $Y_n$ be the state of the system at time $n$. Determine the transition probability matrix $P$. Is $\left\{Y_n: n\geq 0\right\}$ ergodic?

(b) Given $0 < l^{*} < L$. Assume that if $Y_n > l^{*}$, the system is replaced by a new one (aka. back to state $0$ at time $n+1$ from time $n$). Find the new transition probability matrix $P^{*}$.

**My attempt:**

Based on the problem statement, I interpret that in each time period, the system can either degrade by $k$ unit lower with probability $kp$ ($k\in \left\{1, \ldots, M\right\}$), or stay at the same level with probability. Is this the intended interpretation?

Thus, for the two successive time periods $n$ and $n-1$, $P(Y_n = i | Y_{n-1} = j) = (i-j)p$ for $i > j$ (i.e., degrade by $(i-j)$ units). For $i = j$, $P(Y_n = i | Y_{n-1} = j) = P(Y_n = j | Y_{n-1} = j) = 1-\sum_{k=1}^{M} kp$ (no degrade). For $i<j$, $P(Y_n = i |  Y_{n-1} = j) = 0$.

Thus, the one-step transition probability matrix is (bear in mind that the rows read as $0$ to $M$ from top to bottom, and the columns read as $0$ to $L$ from left to right):

$$
P=
\pmatrix{
1-p\sum_{k=1}^{M} k & p & 2p &\cdots & Mp\\
0 & (1 - p\sum_{k=1}^{M-1} k) &p &\cdots &(M-1)p\\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots\\
0 &0 & \cdots & 1-p & p\\
0 &0 & 0 &\cdots & 1
}
$$

Looking at the transition probability matrix $P$, it is straightforward that $\left\{Y_n: n\geq 0\right\}$ is **not** ergodic, because we cannot find a $n$ such that $P_{Lj}^{n} > 0$ for $j = 1, 2, \ldots, L-1$.

(b) In this case, all the rows from $0$ to $l*$ of matrix $P*$ will be exactly the same as in
$P$, and all the rows after $l*$-th row will have the form $[1 \ 0 \ 0 \ldots 0$] corresponding to columns $0$ to $L$. Once again, from this matrix $P*$, we can show that $\left\{Y_n: n\geq 0\right\}$ is ergodic.

**My question:** Can anyone please let me know if my solutions above are correct?

Comment: Nobody is willing to give me some help on the above problem? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the interpretation is right. In one period, there is either a degradation of $1$ unit, or the machine stays in its current state with probability $1-p$. So the one-step probability matrix is not what you have written, but is far simpler. (This is part $a$) On why it is ergodic, you are right(for part $a$).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: thank you for your thought. If your thought is correct, what do you think of my solution to part (b)? I think $P*$ has to be ergodic, and the matrix is pretty much the same as part (a) except all the rows starting from $l*+1$ to $L$ would have the form $[1\ \ 0 \cdots 0]$

Comment: Is it ergodic? If I start at a point after $L+1$ I can never return to that point, right? (The transition matrix is correct).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: But the system is always replaced when its state $> l^{*}$. So even when you start at a point after $L+1$ (which is not possible, given the problem context), you always get back to state $0$ at the next time period. Then you can go to every other states.

Comment: Pardon me. What I meant is this : for example take $L=5$ and $l^* = 2$. Then if I start at $3$, I cannot come back at $3$, because to get to $3$ I have to hit $2$, but then I again go back to $0$.

Comment: I see what you meant. For your example, the system still hits to $3$ first before it got back to state $0$, no? For example, if it starts from $3$, it can go as: $3 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0$. So you can come back to $3$. But it is not ergodic because it cannot get to a further state than $l^{*}+1$ (because at each time period, the system state can only degrade by exactly $0$ or $1$ unit, and the system state keeps coming back to state $0$ after state $l^{*}+1$). So your initial thought were right. (thank you!)

Comment: You are welcome! If I want to answer this question, would it be fine if I rephrased these comments above for the answer?

Comment: Totally fine with me :)

Comment: Written. Kindly upvote and accept if it is good, thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had started off by pointing out that the interpretation of the system is wrong. Indeed, in one step either there was no degradation, or degradation by one unit, therefore the transition matrix was far simpler than you wrote it (Look up Gambler's ruin as well). It is indeed not ergodic, since you can't return to $0$ starting from $1$, for example. This was subsequently noted by you.

Your transition probabilities are fine for the second one. However, the second system is also not ergodic , because for $l^* <k <L$, a system starting at $k$ goes to $0$, then cannot hit $k$ since in the middle it will hit $l^*$ and again go back to $0$.